# How to deploy a UWP to a Galaxy TabPro S with windows 10 OS?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, uwp, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to deploy a UWP app from my Alienware 18, Laptop with Windows 10, version 1803 to a Tablet Galaxy TabPro S with Windows 10 version 1803 as well.

I had activated developer mode on the device target and the USB device discovery option as well.
First I tried connecting a USB Cable from my laptop to the tablet which has a USB-C port.

But My laptop doesn't even find it.

What I want is to find a way to deploy a UWP from my laptop to the tablet, I made some research and I found out that, only HoloLens and Windows Phone 10, are findable using USB Connection.

So what step should I follow to successfully remote debug my app to a windows 10 Tablet.

I would appreciate details because I tried to follow remote deploying but I haven't been able to successfully find the tablet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows 10 on your tablet, just like on your development machine, supports remotely debugging over the network rather than over USB.  Make sure both machines are in developer mode, with the other machine also having Device Discovery turned on as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#device-discovery).  Both should connect to your WiFi as a private network.  After that it should be as simple as configuring your project to deploy to the other machine, rather than locally, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-on-a-remote-machine?view=vs-2017#BKMK_ConnectVS) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#specifying-a-remote-device).  Don't forget to pair them with a PIN.

If you host a web API on your development machine, configure your firewall as described [here](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/02/27/remote-access-to-local-aspnet-core-apps-from-mobile-devices/).

Answer (score 0):

Use remote debugging over at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2017

Make sure you follow the instructions, sometimes remote debugging is barred by firewall so check that.

Alternative right click your main project, go to store then click create packages for sideloading and then send the package over at your Samsung device.

Answer (score 0):

> So what step should I follow to successfully remote debug my app to a windows 10 Tablet.

To run a UWP app on a remote machine, you must attach to it using the Remote Tools for Visual Studio.

In some scenarios, the remote tools are automatically installed when you deploy to a remote device. For example,

> For Windows 10 PCs running Creators Update and later versions, remote tools will be installed automatically.

Then, your remote device and the Visual Studio computer must be connected over a network or connected directly through a USB or Ethernet cable. Debugging over the internet is not supported.

After that, you need to configure the Visual Studio project for remote debugging. In the properties of the project, select the **Debug** and choose the **Remote Machine** from the **Target Device** list. In general, I will input the remote machine's IP address, you could choose **Find** to choose the device from the Select **Remote Debugger Connection** dialog box.

Next step, please move to your Tablet, you need to **Set up the remote debugger**. You must have administrative permissions on the remote computer. Then, open the Start menu and search for Remote Debugger. If you could find it, just start it normally. If you cannot find it, you need to install it Remote Tools manually. See this link to [Download and Install the remote tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2017#download-and-install-the-remote-tools). Once the Remote Debugger started, you could do some configurations. After that, you could choose **Start Debugging** on the **Debug** menu (Keyboard: F5). The project is recompiled, then deployed to and started on the remote device. Please read [Run UWP apps on a remote machine in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-on-a-remote-machine?view=vs-2017) for more information.